# How to detect if cronned script is stuck

Tags: perl, unix, cron

I have a few Perl scripts on a Solaris SunOS system which basically connect to other nodes on the network and fetch/process command logs. They run correctly 99% of the time when run manually, but sometimes they get stuck. In this case, I simply interrupt it and run again.

Now, I intend to cron them, and I would like to know if there is a way to detect if the script got stuck in the middle of execution (for whatever reason), and preferably exit as soon as that happens, in order to release any system resources it may be occupying.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: The hanging of the script is due to intermittent network issues at the remote end, which is out of my control.

Comment: Not sure what e.g. `ps` output looks like on Solaris, but if a process is in I/O wait for a long time, that would seem like a useful problem indicator. However, agree that it would be even better to fix the code to not get stuck in blocking I/O states.

Comment: Indeed, it would be far better to fix the code, but in a more general sense, I was looking for a way to detect such problematic scripts, specially when run via cron. Thanks for your suggestions though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TMTOWTDI, but one possibility:

1. At the start of your script, write the process id to a temporary file.
2. At the end of the script, remove the temporary file.
3. In another script, see if there are any of these temporary files more than a few minutes/hours old.